# Get specific lines from a txt file paragraphs and write them on one line

Tags: vbscript

I have a txt file like that:

```
GLP
07-Sep-2017
09:13

8.186 pH
-59.5 mV
25.5 ºC ATC
Manual EP
PRO_ISM
6270340
Last cal.: 14-Aug-2017  14:51
S210
B625637220
EMF





GLP
07-Sep-2017
08:43

8.180 pH
-59.2 mV
25.5 ºC ATC
Manual EP
PRO_ISM
6270340
Last cal.: 14-Aug-2017  14:51
S210
B625637220
EMF





GLP
07-Sep-2017
08:13

8.180 pH
-59.2 mV
25.6 ºC ATC
Manual EP
PRO_ISM
6270340
Last cal.: 14-Aug-2017  14:51
S210
B625637220
EMF

...
```

I would like to obtain:

```
07-Sep-2017,08:43, ,8.180 pH,-59.2 mV,25.5 ºC ATC
07-Sep-2017,08:13, ,8.180 pH,-59.2 mV,25.6 ºC ATC
07-Sep-2017,07:43, ,8.180 pH,-59.2 mV,25.6 ºC ATC
```

I already wrote the VBScript below but I obtain everything on the same line, like:

```
,07-Sep-2017,08:43, ,8.180 pH,-59.2 mV,25.5 ºC ATC,07-Sep-2017,08:13, ,8.180 pH,-59.2 mV,25.6 ºC ATC,07-Sep-2017,07:43, ,8.180 pH,-59.2 mV,25.6 ºC ATC
```

I didn't find the way to put my `vbCrLf` after my first block.

Do you have an idea?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Jean\Desktop\pH\M092735.TXT", 1)
Set objTextFile2 = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Jean\Desktop\pH\ph.txt", 8)

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream = False
    Line = objTextFile.ReadLine

    If Line = "GLP" Then
        For i = 1 To 6
            strLine = strLine & "," & objTextFile.ReadLine
        Next
        strLine2 = strLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop

objTextFile2.write strLine2

objTextFile.Close
objTextFile2.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just tell you what the problems are in point form:

1. The comparison.  I can't see how this will work.  `ReadLine` will return a string including the trailing spaces.  The comparison needs to be changed to

   ```
   If Left(Line, 3) = "GLP" Then
   ```
2. `strLine` is not reset.  It concatenates the previous result to the next result so the data grows exponentially.  Add this between the `If` and the `For` statement

   ```
   strLine = ""
   ```
3. Only the last line will be saved.  To save all the lines, the `strLine2` statement needs to be changed to

   ```
   strLine2 = strLine2 & strLine & vbCrLf
   ```

   Alternatively, you could remove the write after the loop and change the concatenation to

   ```
   objTextFile2.WriteLine strLine
   ```
4. The symbol you're using for degrees is the **masculine ordinal indicator** (Unicode U+00BA) instead of the degrees symbol (Unicode U+00B0).  This is a very common mistake.  What you will notice is that when you view the data, sometimes it shows as a degree symbol with an underline.

Comment: Just rechecked the data - it has trailing spaces, not CRLF.  Answer corrected.

Comment: It's not clear whether the trailing spaces are in the actual input data. The OP may have added them in the question to get the lines to break correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! It works perfect.

```
strLine = ""
```

was the thing

Here the complete working code

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Jean\Desktop\pH\M092735.TXT", 1)
Set objTextFile2 = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Jean\Desktop\pH\ph.txt", 8)

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream=false
    Line = objTextFile.ReadLine

If Line = "GLP" Then
    strLine = ""
    For i = 1 to 6
    strLine = strLine & "," & objTextFile.ReadLine
    Next
    strLine2 = strLine2 & strLine & vbcrlf
End If
Loop

    objTextFile2.writeline strLine2

objTextFile.Close
objTextFile2.Close
```